# How to make .then completely finish before moving onto the next?

Tags: javascript, promise, backendless

So, I'm adding an establishment to the database, then adding a special to the database. An establishment can have 1 to Many specials, so I'm trying to create a relation under the 3rd `.then()`. The thing is, then 3rd `.then()` is executing before an establishment and special is added to the database. I need to add the establishment and special to the database first because I need to obtain their objectIds, `var establishmentObjectId;` and `var specialObjectId;`

How can I go about making sure the the establishment and special objectIds are retrieved before the relation is made?

```
    //Save the establishment objectId
    var establishmentObjectId;
    //Save the special objectID
    var specialObjectId;

    //Save establishment
    .then(() => {
        //Get the add form data
        var addName = document.getElementById('add_name');
        var addCountry = document.getElementById('add_country');
        var addEstablishmentType = document.getElementById('add_establishment_type');
        var addCuisineType = document.getElementById('add_cusine_type');

        //Create establishment from user's enteries
        var establishment = {
            Name: addName.value,
            Address: addAddress.value,
            Suburb: addSuburb.value,
            Country: addCountry.value,
            Cuisine_Type: addCuisineType.value,
            Establishment_Type: addEstablishmentType.value
        }

        //Save establishment to db
        Backendless.Data.of('Establishment').save( establishment )
        .then( function( savedObject ) {
            establishmentObjectId = savedObject.objectId;
            console.log( "new Establishment instance has been saved" );
          })
        .catch( function( error ) {
            console.log( "an error has occurred " + error.message );
          });
    })
    //Save special
    .then(() => {
        //Get the add form data
        var addCategory = document.getElementById('add_category');
        var addTypeOfSpecial = document.getElementById('add_type_of_special');
        var addDescription = document.getElementById('add_description');

        //Create special from user's enteries
        var special = {
            Category: addCategory.value,
            Type_Of_Special: addTypeOfSpecial.value,
            Description: addDescription.value
        }

        //Save special to db
        Backendless.Data.of('Special').save( special )
        .then( function( savedObject ) {
            specialObjectId = savedObject.objectId;
            console.log( "new Special instance has been saved" );
            })
        .catch( function( error ) {
            console.log( "an error has occurred " + error.message );
            });
    })
    //Add special to establishment/form relation
    .then(() => {

        //These are undefined even though they are declared above
        console.log(establishmentObjectId);
        console.log(specialObjectId);

        var parentObject = { objectId:establishmentObjectId };
        var childObject = { objectId:specialObjectId };
        var children = [ childObject ];

        Backendless.Data.of( "Establishment" ).addRelation( parentObject, "establishmentSpecials", children )
        .then( function( count ) {
          console.log( "relation has been set" );
        })
        .catch( function( error ) {
          console.log( "server reported an error - " + error.message );
        });

    })
```

Many thanks

Comment: Return the promise you want to wait for, when it completes the next `.then` will be executed

Comment: create promise chain, return promise in then. it will try to resolve it. `return  Backendless.Data.of( "Establishment" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you're in a Promise chain, 99% of the time, when you create a new Promise (with an API call, or with `new Promise`, etc), you should return it, or otherwise put it together with something else (like a `Promise.all` and return *that*). This will mean that possible rejections can be handled at a higher level, and will mean that the *next* `.then` in a chain will start only once the prior `.then` finishes.

Change every

```
Backendless.Data.of(
```

to

```
return Backendless.Data.of(
```

Also, you probably *don't* want to be `catch`ing at every level, like you're doing currently - whenever you `catch`, you turn a rejected Promise into a resolved Promise, and subsequent `.then`s may be running on the assumption that everything in the prior `.then` finished successfully. With sequential asynchronous operations like these, if there's an error *anywhere*, you probably want to stop the whole process, rather than try to continue anyway (which could result in bugs).

For example, if `Backendless.Data.of('Establishment').save` fails, then `establishmentObjectId` never gets assigned to, and trying to use it later in the final `.then` won't work. Same sort of thing with `specialObjectId`.

For this code, there's also a better pattern to follow: instead of using two separate `.then`s, one to get the `establishmentObjectId` and one to get the `specialObjectId`, consider letting those operations run in parallel, and run the final `.then` after they're done via `Promise.all`. Something along the lines of:

```
const getEstablishmentObjectId = () => {
  //Get the add form data
  // ...
  //Create establishment from user's enteries
  var establishment = {
    // ...
  }
  //Save establishment to db
  return Backendless.Data.of('Establishment').save(establishment)
    .then(savedObject => savedObject.objectId);
};
const getSpecialObjectId = () => {
    // ...
    return Backendless.Data.of('Special').save(special)
      .then(savedObject => savedObject.objectId);
};

Promise.all([
  getEstablishmentObjectId(),
  getSpecialObjectId(),
]).then(([establishmentObjectId, specialObjectId]) => {
    console.log(establishmentObjectId);
    console.log(specialObjectId);
    var parentObject = {
      objectId: establishmentObjectId
    };
    // etc
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error', error);
  });
```